# Laplace transform of derivative.

Tags: laplace-transform

I am trying to solve Laplace transform of derivative.
While looking at some examples

For f(t)=t^2

We find Laplace transform of second derivative.

For e^(at)

We find Laplace transform of first derivative.

My question is how do I know wether I should find Laplace transform of first , second or nth derivative

Comment: https://mathalino.com/reviewer/advance-engineering-mathematics/laplace-transforms-derivatives